# actualizar registro que estén en minúscula en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

buenas tardes saludos necesito que me ayuden con una consulta en MySql para actualizar todos los registros que estén en minúsculas

Existe una tabla

```
CREATE TABLE `cliente` (
`nombre` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
`apellido` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
`status` INT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
;
```

y tengo mil registros unos en mayúsculas y otros en minúsculas

el campo `status` debo cambiarlo pero solo los que tienen el campo `nombre` en minusculas

entiendo que es un simple `where` junto a un `uppercase` algo así, pero de verdad no tengo idea de como lograrlo gracias por su tiempo saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que el `collation` al ser `latin1_swedish_ci` es `case insensitive`. Es decir, `HOLA` <>  `hola`. Lo que si puedes hacer es verifica usando un `collation` que sea sensible, por ejemplo:

```
UPDATE cliente
     SET STATUS = <valor>
     FROM cliente
     WHERE nombre COLLATE 'latin1_general_cs' =  lower(nombre);
```

Para consultar los `collation` que son sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas, puedes hacer:

```
SHOW COLLATION WHERE COLLATION LIKE  "%_cs";
```

Comment: `'WHERE nombre COLLATE 'latin1_general_cs'  = 'carlos';'` esto no seria modificrlo uno a uno? tengo mas de milregistros

Comment: @GilbertoAsuaje, No, es un ejemplo nomas, ahí edite como debiera ser para comparar sobre la misma tabla

Comment: no, me da error 1064. pero estamos cerca

Comment: @GilbertoAsuaje, el error 1064, es básicamente error de sintaxis. Hay algo que está mal escrito. Revisa la sintaxis, en este fiddle al menos funciona: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba70ec/1

Comment: listo copie y pegue y funciono, seguro me falto una coma algo así muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si comparas el campo nombre contra el mismo forzandolo a minúsculas y son iguales, es que es minúscula. Esto funcionará siempre y cuando todo el nombre esté en minúscula.

```
UPDATE CLIENTE SET
    STATUS = // Valor que se desee guardar
WHERE LOWER(NOMBRE) = NOMBRE;
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo pero ya hice eso y me actualiza a todos no importa que este en minúsculas o mayúsculas